# curl aternative to InternetReadFile

Tags: c, libcurl

I wanted to check whether curl has any alternative like InternetReadFile which returns the content with size specified in the buffer size.

I have used:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, Read_Cb);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &ReadBuffer);
curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
```

But my Read_Cb gets called back multiple time (which is documented behaviour) and that is fine.
I want curl_easy_perform to return when my buffer size is reached. I explored CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, but that doesn't seem to help here.

CURLE_WRITE_ERROR is a problem becuase it aborts the transfer. I could have returned something from my callback which will gracefully tell curl to return curl_easy_perform.

Answer (score 0):

Does [CURLOPT_RANGE](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RANGE.html) help?

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl)
{
    size_t from = 0, to = 1024;
    char range[64];

    snprintf(range, sizeof range, "%zu-%zu", from, to);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RANGE, range);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This perhaps should work. Not sure whether sending range request everytime is the right way.

Comment: and yes, few servers may not support (or ignore) range request.

Comment: Any option apart from range request. if not, is it not a limitation of cur ?

Answer (score 0):

If the server supports range requests, use HTTP Range:

```
CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl) {
  char range[32];
  const size_t size = 65536;
  snprintf(range, sizeof(range), "0-%zu", size - 1);
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://httpbin.org/range/65536");
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RANGE, range);
  curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
```

See [CURLOPT_RANGE](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RANGE.html) for more details.

If the server does not support range requests, use a [progress](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION.html) or a [write](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) function to terminate the request if the size is reached.

```
const size_t size = 65535;

struct memory {
  char* response;
  size_t size;
};
 
static size_t cb(void* data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp) {
  size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
  struct memory* mem = (struct memory*)userp;
  
  if (mem->size + realsize > size)
    realsize = size - mem->size;

  char* ptr = realloc(mem->response, mem->size + realsize);
  if (ptr == NULL)
    return 0;  /* out of memory! */
 
  mem->response = ptr;
  memcpy(&(mem->response[mem->size]), data, realsize);
  mem->size += realsize;
 
  /* if realsize < size * nmemb, this will cause the transfer to get
     aborted and curl_easy_perform will return URLE_WRITE_ERROR */
  return realsize;
}
 
struct memory chunk = {0};
 
CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

if (curl) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://httpbin.org/stream-bytes/131072");

  /* send all data to this function  */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, cb);
 
  /* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */
  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)&chunk);

  curl_easy_perform(curl);
}
```

If URLE_WRITE_ERROR is not desired, you can use `curl_multi_perform(multi, &running_handles)` and remove handle from `multi` if size reached. See [curl_multi_remove_handle](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_remove_handle.html) for more details.

Comment: thank you. I was thinking of URLE_WRITE_ERROR. but thought whether aborting is a good option or not?  Also the next read would still happen from the beginning and not like other reads where it continues from the next location. Again an issue to be addressed .

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean. Where is next read in your code, what is location where it continues, what is addressed issue?

Comment: Sorry to be unclear. I wanted to know whether there is a mechanism to start my next read(download) from a specified location. When I say InternetReadFile(100 bytes), the next InternetReadFile starts from 101 byte. But not able to find any such option in curl. i.e. I want to start my next read from 101 byte and not from begining.

Comment: What is the original task you are trying to solve? It looks like you dive into solving the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: The original task is to download a file. If paused, the number of bytes downloaded is maintained. When resumed (which can be anytime), the resume must start from the paused location.